# Proper way to show ionic modal with textarea and keyboard

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a modal for sending a message, and in order to get the keyboard to show, I have to set the focus on the `textarea` after triggering the modal.

HTML

```
  <script id="new-post.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div class="modal">
    <form ng-submit="sendPost(post)">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
          <button class="button button-clear button-light" ng-click="closeNewPost()">Cancel</button>
          <h1 class="title">New Message</h1>
          <button type="submit" class="button button-clear">Post</button>          
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>

          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <textarea class="textareas" id="postMessageInput" ng-model="$parent.post.message" placeholder="What do you want to say?"  autofocus ></textarea>
            </label>
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-post.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.postModal = modal;
}, {
   scope: $scope,
   focusFirstInput: true
});
$scope.newPost = function() {
    $scope.postModal.show().then(document.getElementById('postMessageInput').focus());    
};
```

What happens is that the modal slides up first, then the keyboard slides up. Sometimes there's a flicker of the screen while the modal first shows. The whole experience is not smooth at all. Sometimes the textarea is even pushed up under the modal header.

Ideally, I want the modal to slide up with the keyboard already rendered on the view, as though the keyboard is embeded into the modal. That's how other apps (ios) seem to work. Is that possible, or is there a standard method for showing the modal with a keyboard and textarea?

Comment: I should add that once the keyboard is shown (only because of focus being set on textarea) that focus is no longer on the textarea and you need to click in the text area before typing.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the flickering of screen by setting disabling of screen to true:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
```

[Checkout Ionic Keyboard iOS Notes here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/)

Answer (score 0):

The ionic [keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) has a `Keyboard.show();` function.
So I would assume:

```
   $scope.newPost = function() {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();   
        // set a timeout of 100 here (maybe)
        $scope.postModal.show().then(document.getElementById('postMessageInput').focus());
    };
```

not tested.

Note: This is only for android. But I think the flickering just appears on that laggy bitch, right?